# JQuery.Ajax Success but just returns server PHP code as text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am running a very simple Jquery.Ajax call as a test. The code should work as it is an example from a programming class.  However, on my Windows XAMPP, all I get back in the alert is the ajax.php code in html format...  I do get a success 200 code though from the Ajax query.  I'm at a loss for what is wrong.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Ajax.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
   useJQuery();
});

function useJQuery() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { i_want_text:'yes' },
        success: function (response) { alert(response); },
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax.php

```
<? 
    if ($_POST["i_want_text"]) {
        print "text received with value of " . $_POST["i_want_text"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you just see the entire contents of the Ajax.php file coming up in the alert? Not sure what you mean about "in HTML format" when there is no HTML in your PHP file.

Comment: in ajax.php change change opening <? to <?php

Comment: `<?` are called short-tags. The interpretation of these short tags can be turned off in the `php.ini` file. So it is always safer to use the `<?php` form for the php start tag. If they are turned off the script will not be interpreted as php code but just as normal text and returned to the caller as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

```
PHP allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).`

so In ajax.php change <? to <?php
```